# Foxx url for ArangoDB version capture

Tags: arangodb

Is there any inbuilt endpoint in default foxx app to get the running Arangodb version. 
We have a monitoring tool and wants to capture arangodb version using a url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [version endpoint](https://docs.arangodb.com/devel/HTTP/MiscellaneousFunctions/#return-server-version)?